# How can I replace everything between 2nd "." and “:” in java?

Tags: java, regex

Been researching online but haven't been able to find a solution.

I've got the following string '555.8.0.i5:790.2.0.i19:904.1.0:8233.2:' in Java.

Whats the best way I can remove everything from and including the second dot to the colon?
I want the string to end up looking like this: `555.8:790.2:904.1:8233.2:`

I saw on another post someone had referenced the second dot with java regex **(\d+.\d.)** but I'm not sure how to do the trim.

EDIT:
I have tried the following java regex `.replaceAll("\\.(.*?):", ":");` but it seems to remove everything from the first dot. Not sure how to get it to trim from the second dot.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Make use String.indexOf and String.substring. Or use the iterate + copy approach with a simple state engine to decide what to skip. Its not hard.

Comment: @TemporalWolf sorry was too quick to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you may use

```
.replaceAll("(\\.[^:.]+)\\.[^:]+", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0O3qN8/2)

**Details**:

- `(\\.[^:.]+)` - Capture group 1 capturing a dot and 1+ chars other than a literal dot and colon
- `\\.` - a literal dot
- `[^:]+` - 1+ chars other than a colon.

In the replacement pattern, only a `$1` backreference to the value captured in Group 1 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use regex?  Here is a solution using Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "555.8.0.i5:790.2.0.i19:904.1.0:8233.2:";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //Split the string into an array of strings at each colon
    String[] stringParts = myString.split(":");

    //Loop over each substring
    for (String stringPart : stringParts) {
        //Find the index of the second dot
        int secondDotIndex = stringPart.indexOf('.', 1 + stringPart.indexOf('.', 1));

        //If a second dot exists then remove everything after and including the dot
        if (secondDotIndex != -1) {
            stringPart = stringPart.substring(0, secondDotIndex);
        }

        //Append each string part and colon back to the final string
        sb.append(stringPart);
        sb.append(":");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The final println prints `555.8:790.2:904.1:8233.2:`